# Developing for Android using bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am new at developing for android and while developing an android app that uses bluetooth, I understand that I need to add permissions to use bluetooth in xml file.

I did so but upon running on my device, the app would not utilize the bluetooth. 
Upon looking carefully under Manage Applications in Android I see that the app does not have bluetooth permission.

The only permissions I have for the app are: personal information, and storage.

I was wondering if there is something wrong with in the way I am uploading my app to the device. I am doing so with the command:

```
cd C:\Android\Bluetooth\bin\adb -d install BlueToothTest-debug.apk
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.VersionOne0"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="BlueToothTest"
              android:debuggable="true">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: why are you having the user permission inside the activity tag?

Comment: Rolled back 3rd party edit which made the question less clear, removed an observation key to understanding the problem, and introduced grammatical errors.  Please only make edits which are both *necessary* and *improvements*.

Answer (score 0):

You have your permission inside the `<application>` tag. It should be like this:

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

At the same level the `<application>` tag.

Comment: Thanks System.exit. That was silly mistake . I did not see the application tag. But thanks a lot!